# sweetalert2 save form input

Tags: javascript, php

i've made this sweetalert but i have a problem, i would like the password entered in the input to be saved (via the php code in the data.php file) to a txt file. The form works (i'm able to insert the password) but the password inserted is not saved to a txt file.

SWAL CODE :

```
swal({
title: 'Submit to confirm',
html:
    '<input id="swal-input1" placeholder="Password" class="form-control mb-1" type="password">',
showCancelButton: true,
confirmButtonText: 'Submit',
showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
buttonsStyling: false,
confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg',
cancelButtonClass: 'btn btn-lg',
preConfirm: function () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            resolve({
                Password: $('input[placeholder="Password"]').val()
            });


        });
},
allowOutsideClick: false
}).then(function (result) {
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        data:Password,
        url:'data.php',
        success:function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
 }).catch(swal.noop)
```

PHP CODE (that save the input value to a txt file) --> data.php

```
<?php
$txt = "data.txt"; 
if (isset($_GET['swal-input1'])) { 
$fh = fopen($txt, 'a'); 
$txt=$_GET['swal-input1']; 
fwrite($fh,$txt); // Write information to the file
fclose($fh); // Close the file
}
?>
```

Thank you, hope you help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the revision.

basically update the data section of your ajax request

`data:{'swal-input1':$('input[placeholder="Password"]').val()},`

Full code

```
swal({
title: 'Submit to confirm',
html:
    '<input id="swal-input1" placeholder="Password" class="form-control mb-1" type="password">',
showCancelButton: true,
confirmButtonText: 'Submit',
showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
buttonsStyling: false,
confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg',
cancelButtonClass: 'btn btn-lg',
preConfirm: function () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            resolve({
                Password: $('input[placeholder="Password"]').val()
            });


        });
},
allowOutsideClick: false
}).then(function (result) {
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        data:{'swal-input1':$('input[placeholder="Password"]').val()},
        url:'data.php',
        success:function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
 }).catch(swal.noop)
```